# Display ajax result from php in jquery popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, popup

I have the following code.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "insert_sp.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: {submit: 'true'},
  success: function(response) {
    
    var data = JSON && JSON.parse(response) || $.parseJSON(response);
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

They displayed `$ReturnMessage`, the result displayed retrieved from PHP using ajax after a new user is being added. Now, I want them to be displayed in a popup.

I've tried some examples on the internet and I figured I need help.

Here's the code :

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $UserId=$_POST["UserId"];
  $UserPwd=$_POST["UserPwd"];

  $stmt = odbc_exec($conn, "CALL UserInsert('$UserId','$UserPwd',)");

  if ($stmt) {
    if (odbc_fetch_row($stmt)) {
      $ReturnStatus=odbc_result($stmt,'ReturnStatus');
      $ReturnMessage=odbc_result($stmt,'ReturnMessage');
    }

    if(isset($ReturnStatus) && $ReturnStatus==1) {
      $ReturnMessage=odbc_result($stmt,'ReturnMessage');
    } 
  }

  $ReturnMessage = utf8_encode ($ReturnMessage);
  echo json_encode($ReturnMessage);
}
?>
```

Here the script I tried to implement the popup. There is no error but the popup didn't come out.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
```

**Script**

```
function showPopup() {
    $("#popup").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        resizable: false,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        draggable: true
    });
}

function closePopup() { 
    $("#popup").dialog('close'); 
}

function submit(data) {   
    $.ajax({
        url: "insert_sp.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {submit: 'true'},
        success: function(response) {
        {
            showPopup();
            $('#popup').html(response);
            $("#popup").dialog('open'); 

            var data = JSON && JSON.parse(response) || $.parseJSON(response);
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: is it showing Any Error??

Comment: So technically you need to replace `alert(data);` by a better looking popup ? `$('#popup').html(data);` ?

Comment: There is no error. The `$ReturnMessage` didn't displayed in a popup. @Raman

Comment: @Lambasoft . There is no popup to begin with. The `$ReturnMessage` is displayed below my user form, not in a popup.

Comment: `$('#popup').html(response);` is wrong. 
response is an Object and not a string, you should parse it first, which you did in `var data = JSON && JSON.parse(response) || $.parseJSON(response);`

Comment: And since we have no idea of the plugin you're using to show the popup, try adding `showPopup();` before you change it's HTML. Maybe showPopup() resets the HTML content of #popup everytime called, this hack fixes it.

Comment: I'm sorry, bare with me. This kind of first time I cooperate with jquery. Should I replace `$('#popup').html(response);` with `$('#popup').html(data);` and position these lines `$('#popup').html(data);` and `showPopup();` after `var data = JSON && JSON.parse(response) || $.parseJSON(response);` ? @Lambasoft

Comment: in your success function first call showPopup(); then do $('#popup').html(response); then call $("#popup").dialog('open');

Comment: The popup still doesn't show up. @Jabs

Comment: have you included jquery ui css?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />` is this the one? @Jabs

Comment: it is giving 404, try //code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Comment: Nope, still no popup. I updated my question with the plugin that I used, maybe I miss something there. Do you mind check them @Jabs

Comment: Do I need to add anything on the html? @Jabs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137919/discussion-between-jabs-and-mint).

Comment: Note that in success function you have given one extra curly braces."success: function(response) {{"

Comment: @AKSHAYJAIN Thanks for catching that.